# post data to web form changing source ip address

Tags: forms, post, curl

Is it possible to post data to a web form using curl but changing the source ip address?

If curl can't help me, any other idea?

thanks for your time
-A

Answer (score 1):

This is [addressed in the curl FAQ](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/faq.html#Can_I_make_libcurl_fake_or_hide), and the answer from there is:

> No. libcurl operates on a higher level. Besides, faking IP address
>   would imply sending IP packet with a made-up source address, and then
>   you normally get a problem with receiving the packet sent back as they
>   would then not be routed to you!
>
> If you use a proxy to access remote sites, the sites will not see your
>   local IP address but instead the address of the proxy.
>
> Also note that on many networks NATs or other IP-munging techniques
>   are used that makes you see and use a different IP address locally
>   than what the remote server will see you coming from. You may also
>   consider using http://www.torproject.org .

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of **`CURLOPT_PROXY`** and **`CURLOPT_POST`** to achieve your problem.
An example code below.

```
<?php
    $url = 'http://somesite.com/form.php';
    $proxy = '127.0.0.1:8888';
    $postVar ='postvar1=value1&postvar2=value2&postvar3=value3';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$postVar);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    $curl_page = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    echo $curl_page;
```